# How to get friday to friday weeks from two date range using moment

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to get week start as friday & end date as friday and I tried to use startOf/endOf week(week/isoweek) but failed. Is there any way that I can get friday as start of week and Friday as end of week using moment.

Moment(date).startOf('week'); // or isoweek

Output should be,
Date of friday

Request data:
First date= 05-09-2019
End date= 05-15-2019(current date)

Expected output:
[
{
  Weekstart: 05-03-2019,
  Weekend: 05-10-2019
},
{
  Weekstart: 05-10-2019,
  Weekend: 05-17-2019
}
]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for setting start day of week . But you can fetch last Friday date using

```
moment().weekday(-2).format("YYYY-DD-MM")
```

Comment: In that case, if I have date like. moment(05-11-2019).weekday(-2); output: 05-03-2019. This is wrong. It should be 05-10-2019 (weekstar:friday) and (weekend: 05-17-2019)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the week start for a locale using something like:

```
moment.updateLocale(moment.locale(), { week: { dow: 5 } })
moment().startOf('week').toString(); // Fri May 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a short custom function to always give you start and end of the week based on a passed `isoWeekDay`:

```js
let getCustomWeek = (dayOfWeek=7, date=new Date()) => {
  let firstDay, lastDay, passedDay = moment(date).isoWeekday(dayOfWeek)
 
  firstDay = moment(passedDay).subtract(1, 'week')
  lastDay = moment(firstDay).add(1, 'week')
 
  return { start: firstDay.format(), end: lastDay.format() }
}

let dateRange = ['05-09-2019', '05-15-2019']

console.log('Friday: ', dateRange.map(d => getCustomWeek(5, new Date(d))))
console.log('Wednesday: ', dateRange.map(d => getCustomWeek(3, new Date(d))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```